# Multiple types with just one object key difference - is there a way to make them generic?

Tags: typescript

I have multiple methods that are almost the same, they just have one different key in their return types. Is there some way to make them generic, so that I only need to enter key name into the generic type?

```
type IsUsersModuleLockedReturnType = {
  isLocked: true,
  usersRestriction: Restriction
} | {
  isLocked: false,
  usersRestriction: null
}

// This type is almost the same as above, but uses different key for restriction. Can I somehow make it generic?
type IsGroupsModuleLockedReturnType = {
  isLocked: true,
  groupsRestriction: Restriction
} | {
  isLocked: false,
  groupsRestriction: null
}
```

The best case for me would be if the key is inferred from the method itself, but I don't know how to do that.

```
public readonly getIsUsersModuleLocked = (): IsUsersModuleLockedReturnType => {
    if ('users' in this.restrictions) {
      return {
        isLocked:true,
        usersRestriction: this.restrictions.users 
      }
    } else {
      return {
        isLocked: false,
        usersRestriction: null
      }
    }
  }
```

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGUEMFsAcBsCmoAuBPWiDOAodnQAlbFAJwEsBjFcgewDtQBeULM8+gcwG48NlibCtTr0szIokq1SAEwA8QjpwA0kpSIYA+XnwIBJLAFUsiUlgCytWQFckAGVqUA1olnEUN0vQAq-CQDeOKCg5FiOLm4AXKikNogqwaA2puaC7Jr0MenCNAw4AL6gAD6gQSFhEa6yMQBmkPCmiSEpZlg5VHlZoPR28IU4OCCgPgAWYaj+Ew3QtGyoo8hYMMiQ4pAARrQAbgmgGzYoyabisuS1tWaI9EeuaKC1MqCkJLmiAHSgAMKQjPqstGgiFGtAA7qBoJBXKEjpxrmYqAB+PTIQwAcVItBssEs1jsiCqbg8Xl8-hY5VC4Sc1RiZHizVAnEx2Par06omybMyhRKZSSlWp0QeDSaSSZWJxHUyMV68H6BUGlHga3EUq6WAAEoh4JhSHyQrAKNtIChkC9ILIGPB7i8NOrOXbRFhuKBBiFpGI6dQZAAKW0Ze3qANOgCU+pCCzC739bwY4hYMfZcaSCqSsBsG3gVGeiAtVvucJQhhMbSstgcgtkEh9IZixdSuPLBMrxO8fgITC04YqtVAPoA5K1zP3QowUOMsNGueqwxSIznPN5u-PKYSanSEkkV8c2mqOZHJ4nMpOh+ItxGFfOitrTMuQi9F4w5yuBZEasLGpvty0G3uGDK+nPEJLwvFM3VAdNM2zc1LXoa1GUQIssAxCVG3xNdq1rUB0WZHEy3QltEJJdtkE7Zdzj7QcGxHDgDynR041nICFxJO8I1fGkNwZbdxRZP9unHKMj3Vd5T1dbcQOA0Ab2QZ97yIpc5PYqk3zqEUv2-XjJWnfdZX6CTzxA1MQmGCxfnuWYXghRCQVkcQsHIaByGVPUUFoBY5lWLZdiSYZIKzSgczzOCC0QwwAAUzCcrAHLjfCKzfd4ksKIA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)

In your case you could do it like:

```js
type genericType<T extends string> = ( { isLocked: true } & { [key in T]: Restriction } ) 
| ( {isLocked: false} & {[key in T]: null} );

type IsUsersModuleLockedReturnType = genericType<"usersRestriction">;
```